# Exclude a file from bash script in Hugo

Tags: bash, hugo, hugo-content-organization

This code converts Hugo's markdown posts to page bundles. However, would anyone kindly help with showing how to edit the code to exclude the `_index.md` file from being converted?

```
for FILE in *.md
do
  # remove the last dot and subsequent chars to name the folder from the .md
  DIR="${FILE%.*}"
  mkdir -p "$DIR"
  mv "$FILE" "$DIR"
done
find ./ -iname '*.md' -execdir mv -i '{}' index.md \;
```

Comment: You can include `if [[ "$FILE" == "_index.md" ]];then continue; fi` after `do` within your loop.

Comment: Adding your code renames `_index.md` to `index.md`

Comment: That probably happens after the loop in find's execdir.

Comment: Try changing your `find` command to `find . \( -iname '*.md' ! -iname '_index.md' \) -execdir mv -i '{}' index.md \;``

Comment: @j_b is this the correct code? `find . ( -iname '*.md' ! -iname '_index.md' ) -execdir mv -i '{}' index.md \;`. Because now none of the files is converted to `index.md`.

Comment: No, the parentheses should be escaped with a backslash.  `find . \( -iname '*.md' ! -iname '_index.md' \) -execdir mv -i '{}' index.md \;`  Looks like the backslashes were removed when I pasted the command in the previous comment.